# How to replace the input checkbox into dropdown using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have a form with checkboxes and the default, all checkboxes are checked, now I want to convert it to dropdown and remain the default setting like in the checkbox. So the values will still be displayed automatically.

I have a js script the convert it to dropdown, but the default settings of checkboxes are removed.

JS

```
(function($){
"use strict"

$(function(){
    var $job_types_select = $('<select class="job_types_select"></select>');
    var $job_types_ul = $('form.job_filters ul.job_types');
    var $job_type_hidden = $('<input type="hidden" name="filter_job_type[]"/>');
        $job_types_ul.find('li').each(function(){
            var $li = $(this);
            var label_text = $li.find('label').text();
            var value = $li.find('input:checkbox').val();
            var $option = $('<option></option>');
            $option.text(label_text);
            $option.attr({value: value});
            $job_types_select.append($option);
            });
            $job_types_select.change(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('input:hidden[name="filter_job_type[]"]').val(value);
                var target = $(this).closest('div.job_listings');
                target.triggerHandler('update_results', [ 1, false ]);
            });
    $job_types_ul.after($job_type_hidden);
    $job_types_ul.replaceWith($job_types_select);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Here's the link: http://bit.do/bLNZx

Comment: @RayonDabre please see the updated question

Comment: Also share the fiddle of the same..

Comment: why are you using javascript for that..? y not server side modification?

Comment: @CerlinBoss because the form that I want to modify is made by the wp plugin

Comment: See if the plugin has a git repo, then try forking the plugin and make changes to it. or built it as a feature and contribute to that repo.. :)

Comment: looks like all checkboxes have some events associated with it and there are  actions taken based on that... so its better to learn the plugin and modify the plugin in the server side..

Comment: @CerlinBoss but i want to do in client-side

Comment: @RayonDabre, i can but im afraid that the output in fiddle will be different